# Правильное резервирование при использовании Робокассы

Tags: php, mysql, робокасса

Использую Робокассу, вся логика согласно документации.
Нашел недостаток то ли  Робокассе, то ли я неправильно использую логику, а именно:

1. Покупатель выбирает столик в ресторане.
2. Мой скрипт ставит **статус** в БД для данного столика - **резерв**, пока столик в резерве, его никто не может поставить в резерв и соответственно  купить.
3. Покупатель переходит на страницу оплаты Робокассы и оплачивает.
4. Мой скрипт получает по Result URL подтверждение и меняет **статус** - **оплачено.**

Как мне снять с резерва, если клиент не станет оплачивать? Тут два варианта развития событий:

1. когда клиент отказался в интерфейсе Робокассы и Робокасса отправляет его на страницу Fail - в этом случае я с этой страницы получаю ответ и меняю в БД **статус** на **свободно**
2. Клиент тупо закрыл страницу оплаты, соответственно Робокасса ничего не отправляет на страницу Fail и столик висит в резерве.

Почему то Робокасса никак этот момент не озвучивает, то есть получайте Fail-ответ на странице Fail и точка. Временно я через крон чищу заказы. которые висят в резерве более 5 минут, то есть однозначно клиент уже должен успеть оплатить, но не красиво же? А еще клиент может какое-то время держать открытым форму оплаты (СБЕР-АЛЬФА 10 минут дают на оплату) и все-таки оплатить, возникает двойственность какая-то.
Кто как решал подобное, поделитесь!!)))

Comment: У вас нормальное решение, не думаю, что стоит переделывать. Единственное - это редактирование интервала времени на отмену резерва. Но это зависит от загруженности вашего заведения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделать скрипт в cron/демон, который освовобождает столики, если оплаты не было 10-15 минут

Comment: ну это почти тоже самое, что я озвучил в вопросе...

Comment: >>Кто как решал подобное, поделитесь!!

вот так и решали. Ничего другого просто нет. Робокасса может вообще ничего не вернуть.

Я обычно делаю 2 обработчика  - fail + cron (демон). Fail освобождает быстрее и чаще. Скрипт из cron высвобождает те которые подвисли из глюков платежных систем

Comment: hardworm - крон с каким периодом используете?

Comment: В зависимости от проект. Для билетов на концерт 15 минут. Для резервирования места в мед. центр 25 минут (народ делает всё очень медленно и вдумчиво - не стоит ему мешать).